# Proper Disposal of Unamanged Struct

Tags: c#, unmanaged

Hello this question is a continuation of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50242234/c-sharp-proper-disposing-of-structure-with-char). Provided below is a short version of the code that is loading the data into the structure. The HDF5DotNet library is found [here](http://hdf5.net/) using the 32 bit version with vs2015. My question is, will MyStruct leak memory when SomeCallerClass call HDF5GetSubGroups?

```
using HDF5DotNet;
namespace CommonClass
{
        public class HDF5FileReader
        {
             public static List<string> HDF5GetSubGroups(string filePath)
             {
                  var returnList = new List<string>();
                  //... some HDF5 instantiating -- commented out for brevity
                  var myStruct = new MyStruct[numberOfThingsToRead];
                  H5A.read(someAttribute, someAttributeType, new H5Array<MyStruct>(myStruct));
                  string myStructVariableString = IntPtrToString(myStruct[0].intPtr);
                  returnList.Add(myStructVariableString);
                  //... closing some HDF5 instantiating -- commented out for brevity
                  return returnList
             }

         private string IntPtrToString(IntPtr ipp)
         {
              string s = Marshal.PtrToStringAnsi(ipp)
              //need to free ipp?
              return s;
         }
     }

     public struct MyStruct
     {
          public Int int1;
          public IntPtr intPtr;
     }
}

namespace CallerClass
{
     public class SomeCallerClass()
     {
         string someFilePath = "Path\To\HDF5File.h5"
         var stringList = HDF5FileReader.HDF5GetSubGroups(someFilePath)
         //Do Something with StringList -- add to observablecollection
     }

     public class UnloadingSomeCallerClass()
     {
          //Clear the observablecollection
     }

}
```

Comment: I read your other question and still not sure why you need `MyStruct`. You can just use a `string` or `char[]`.

Comment: @CodingYoshi According to the HDF5DotNet library [here](http://hdf5.net/FAQ.aspx) the only way I can read variable length strings in the HDF5 file was to use intptr and use Interop.Marshal to convert them to .NET strings. I believe I've tried string and char[] before, but it didn't return me the proper string that was written to the h5 file.

Comment: Ok I see. Please see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6093449/proper-intptr-use-in-c-sharp).

Comment: can you please try to close the file before reading out the pointer? if you put a `H5A.close` directly after the `H5A.read` call, the marshall function should return an error or some weired string. if this is the case you dont neet to free the string.